Does delete policy apply to active segments or only to inactive ones?
Coming from Effective Kafka by Emil Koutanov:

The delete policy operates at the granularity of log segments. A
background process, operating within a replica, looks at each inactive
log segment to determine whether a segment is eligible for deletion.
Recall, only producer-initiated writes are allowed on the active
segment; all other manipulations — deletion and compaction — may only
occur on the inactive segments

But if I have

a test-topic (running Kafka 2.4),
with retention.ms set to 30 seconds
and log.retention.check.interval.ms to 1 second for the broker
and I have just one segment(.log file) - presumably active

and then produce 2-3 messages and stop, after 30ish seconds, the segment file is deleted and a new one is created.
The segment.ms and size are default, so it's not the rolling behavior.
Is the author wrong about how the delete policy may actually work on active segments or am I misunderstanding what active means.

In Kafka, each partition has exactly one active segment that accepts incoming writes. Once this segment reaches configured limits (e.g., segment.ms or segment.bytes), Kafka rolls the segment, creating a new active segment and marking the previous one as inactive.
Retention policies (retention.ms and retention.bytes) apply only to inactive segments by default, as these are no longer receiving writes. Active segments, therefore, are typically exempt from deletion based on retention settings alone.
However
Kafka also includes a mechanism to handle cases where an active segment surpasses the retention.ms limit, even if it hasn’t yet met segment.ms or segment.bytes thresholds. When this happens, Kafka force-rolls the active segment, marking it inactive and making it eligible for deletion under retention policies. This approach ensures that idle segments do not remain open indefinitely when they exceed retention.ms, particularly in low-volume or idle topics.
When Kafka force-rolls and active segment that has breached theretention.ms threshold and has stayed idle, you should see a log like this:
[Log partition=<topic>-<partition>, dir=<log_dir>] Found deletable segments with base offsets [0] due to Retention time 604800ms breach 

See UnifiedLog.scala code for the implementation of this force-roll logic.

Here are some reference links that can help you understand more:

KAFKA-475
KAFKA-4336
Kafka Active Segment Deletion: When and How It Happens


thanks for the excellent answer! The last link especially is precisely what I was after.
